# Issues with unmelting table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

Disclaimer - I'm a biologist, and I have no prior coding experiance.

Hi, so I'm looking at a long-form dataset of blood parameters of Covid-19 patients, and I am facing issues while trying to unmelt it. Here's a small snippet of what the dataset looks like -

| ID_PACIENTE | DE_ANALITO | DE_RESULTADO | CD_UNIDADE | DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | Fosfatase Alcalina | 106 | U/L | 40 - 129 |
| XYZ | Gama-GT | 33 | U/L | 12 a 73 |
| XYZ | ALT (TGP) | 51 | U/L | Até 41 |
| XYZ | DHL | 530 | U/L | 240 a 480 |
| XYZ | Proteína C-Reativa | 1,84 | mg/dL | Ver resultado tradicional |
| XYZ | AST (TGO) | 35 | U/L | Até 40 |
| XYZ | Fibrinogenio | 578 | mg/dL | 200 a 400 |
| XYZ | Dimeros D, quant | 256 | ng/mL | Até 500 |
| XYZ | Hemoglobina | 13,3 | g/dL | 13,5 a 17,5 |

And here's what I want to get to -

| ID_PACIENTE | Fosfatase Alcalina | Gama-GT | ALT (TGP) | DHL | Proteína C-Reativa | AST (TGO) | Fibrinogenio | Dimeros D, quant | Hemoglobina |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA | 40 - 129 U/L | 12 a 73 U/L | Até 41 U/L | 240 a 480 U/L | Ver resultado tradicional mg/dL | Até 40 U/L | 200 a 400 mg/dL | Até 500 ng/mL | 13,5 a 17,5 g/dL |
| XYZ | 106 U/L | 33 U/L | 51 U/L | 530 U/L | 1,84 mg/dL | 35 U/L | 578 mg/dL | 256 ng/mL | 13,3 g/dL |

I've tried using the `dcast()` function, but for some reason I'm ending up with 1's and 0's instead of the values in the original dataset.

How do I get to the wide-form dataset with the original values?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Ali! Please take a look at some highly rated questions on this site to see how a good question should be formatted to make it easier to help you. You need to provide your data in a form that we can easily access to manipulate, and provide the code you have tried so far so that we can modify your existing code rather than having to start from nothing.

Comment: FYI, after my edit (to format as a markdown pipe-table), both of these import into R by copying the contents and `read.table(header=T, 'clipboard', sep='\t')`.

Comment: Ali, this is more than just reshaping: you are combining fields. While not a difficult task, you should make sure that when you ask about reshaping, all that is needed is reshaping, not data-munging as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this requires two steps:

1. Combine the text fields to add units to the numbers.
2. `dcast` twice, once for the reference, once for all patients.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table) # dcast
dat[, DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA := paste(DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA, CD_UNIDADE)] %>%
  .[, DE_RESULTADO := paste(DE_RESULTADO, CD_UNIDADE) ] %>%
  .[, CD_UNIDADE := NULL ]
dat[1:3,]
#    ID_PACIENTE          DE_ANALITO DE_RESULTADO DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA
#         <char>              <char>       <char>              <char>
# 1:        XYZ  Fosfatase Alcalina     106  U/L        40 - 129 U/L 
# 2:        XYZ             Gama-GT      33  U/L         12 a 73 U/L 
# 3:        XYZ           ALT (TGP)      51  U/L          Até 41 U/L 

rbindlist(list(
  dat[, .(ID_PACIENTE = "DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA", DE_ANALITO, DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA)] %>%
    dcast(., ID_PACIENTE ~ DE_ANALITO, value.var = "DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA"),
  dat[, .(ID_PACIENTE, DE_ANALITO, DE_RESULTADO)] %>%
    dcast(., ID_PACIENTE ~ DE_ANALITO, value.var = "DE_RESULTADO")
))
#            ID_PACIENTE  ALT (TGP)   AST (TGO)            DHL  Dimeros D, quant     Fibrinogenio  Fosfatase Alcalina      Gama-GT       Hemoglobina               Proteína C-Reativa 
#                 <char>      <char>      <char>         <char>            <char>           <char>              <char>       <char>            <char>                           <char>
# 1: DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA Até 41 U/L  Até 40 U/L  240 a 480 U/L     Até 500 ng/mL  200 a 400 mg/dL        40 - 129 U/L  12 a 73 U/L  13,5 a 17,5 g/dL  Ver resultado tradicional mg/dL 
# 2:                XYZ     51  U/L     35  U/L       530  U/L        256  ng/mL       578  mg/dL            106  U/L      33  U/L        13,3  g/dL                      1,84  mg/dL
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_wider

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(across(c(DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA, DE_RESULTADO), ~ paste(., CD_UNIDADE))) %>%
  select(-CD_UNIDADE)

bind_rows(
  tidyr::pivot_wider(transmute(dat2, ID_PACIENTE = "DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA", DE_ANALITO, DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA),
                     ID_PACIENTE, names_from = "DE_ANALITO", values_from = "DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA"),
  tidyr::pivot_wider(select(dat2, ID_PACIENTE, DE_ANALITO, DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA),
                     ID_PACIENTE, names_from = "DE_ANALITO", values_from = "DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA")
)
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID_PACIENTE = c("XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ ", "XYZ "), DE_ANALITO = c("Fosfatase Alcalina ", "Gama-GT ", "ALT (TGP) ", "DHL ", "Proteína C-Reativa ", "AST (TGO) ", "Fibrinogenio ", "Dimeros D, quant ", "Hemoglobina "), DE_RESULTADO = c("106 ", "33 ", "51 ", "530 ", "1,84 ", "35 ", "578 ", "256 ", "13,3 "), CD_UNIDADE = c("U/L ", "U/L ", "U/L ", "U/L ", "mg/dL ", "U/L ", "mg/dL ", "ng/mL ", "g/dL "), DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA = c("40 - 129", "12 a 73", "Até 41", "240 a 480", "Ver resultado tradicional", "Até 40", "200 a 400", "Até 500", "13,5 a 17,5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
datout <- structure(list(ID_PACIENTE = c("DE_VALOR_REFERENCIA ", "XYZ "), Fosfatase.Alcalina = c("40 - 129 U/L ", "106 U/L "), Gama.GT = c("12 a 73 U/L ", "33 U/L "), ALT..TGP. = c("Até 41 U/L ", "51 U/L "), DHL = c("240 a 480 U/L ", "530 U/L "), `Proteína.C.Reativa` = c("Ver resultado tradicional mg/dL ", "1,84 mg/dL "), AST..TGO. = c("Até 40 U/L ", "35 U/L "), Fibrinogenio = c("200 a 400 mg/dL ", "578 mg/dL "), Dimeros.D..quant = c("Até 500 ng/mL ", "256 ng/mL "), Hemoglobina = c("13,5 a 17,5 g/dL", "13,3 g/dL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
setDT(dat)
setDT(datout)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.  
  
I ran your code (the first one), and after running the last line of it, I'm getting this error -  
  
    Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: That means there is likely something different about your data that you aren't telling us (whether you know it or not). The way R presents `data.frame` on the console can be ambiguous with some data types, so often the only way to give unambiguous data here on SO is to either build the data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`) or include the output from `dput(x)`, where `x` is a representative sample of your data, perhaps the top so-many-rows. (I think the `dput` way is best in your case.)

Comment: You're right, I've only provided a tiny fraction of the entire dataset ,which I obtained from this site - https://repositoriodatasharingfapesp.uspdigital.usp.br/handle/item/97 (this links to a .zip file, and the dataset is /final/HSL_Exames_2.csv). If you find it difficult to access it, should I add it to the OP as an edit?

Comment: I think you'll find that many choose to not click on unrecognized external links like that. Really, unless the data needs to be big, just use `dput` as I suggested.